# Divide by zero error encountered with Decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 ,(CAST(SUM(Y.[Profit]) AS DECIMAL (18,2)) / CAST(SUM(Y.[Sales]) AS DECIMAL (18,2))) AS 'AHT'
```

Does anyone know where do I put ISNULL or NULLIF so that I wouldn't encounter a 'Divide by zero error encountered' error?

I expect to see NUll or Zero (0)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: It should be `SUM(IFNULL(Y.[Profit]), 0)`

Comment: You check the value you divide with for 0

Comment: I'd try `/ IFNULL(CAST(SUM(Y.[Sales]) AS DECIMAL (18,2)), 0.0)`.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: @jarlh Microsoft SQL

Comment: @IbrahimHammed I need to keep the CAST as well. It doesn't work this way.

Comment: Tried this - ,(CAST(SUM(Y.[THT]) AS DECIMAL (18,2)) / IFNULL(CAST(SUM(Y.[Sales]) AS DECIMAL (18,2)), 0.0) AS 'AHT'  - Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check divider before operation, something like :

```
CASE 
    WHEN SUM(Y.[Sales]) != 0
    THEN (CAST(SUM(Y.[Profit]) AS DECIMAL (18,2)) / CAST(SUM(Y.[Sales]) AS DECIMAL (18,2))) 
    ELSE NULL
END AS 'AHT'
```